# How should I handle NotFound 404 having services and not only simple repositories

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, architecture, asp.net-web-api2

All samples about Web API and return Resource states on the server look like this:

```
var resource = repository.Get(id);
if(resource == null)
{
   return NotFound();
}
return resource;
```

This works in the most simple architectures.

But having much business logic and services calling that repositories I do not see how I can still use this approach.

In our architecture every web api controller gets a service injected and each service gets one or many repositories or even other services injected.

Now my services do not have simple Get methods returning a resource.

These services could look like:

```
action(string materialNumber)
{
   var pdf = service.CreateProductPDF(materialNumber);
  return pdf;
}


class Service
{
   public XXX CreateProductPDF(string materialNumber)
   {
       // Do repository call here but HOW do I let the action know that the materialNumber does not exist?

       // Create product pdf from materialNumber


   }
}
```

**My question is inside the comment above.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain should be able to transport a *value object* from the repository to service.

That *value object* can be called `DomainResult` and it should contain both the domain objects you're requesting along with domain validation information (i.e. *broken rules*).

For example:

```
// It's an OVERSIMPLIFICATION, but it should give you the hint
// to keep you in the right track...
// This code requires C# 6 as it's using expression-bodied properties!
public class DomainResult<TResult>
{
    public TResult Result { get; set; }
    public List<BrokenRule> BrokenRules { get; } = new List<BrokenRule>();
    public bool IsSuccessful => BrokenRules.Count == 0;
}
```

For example, your method might look like this:

```
class Service
{
   public DomainResult<PdfDocument> CreateProductPDF(string materialNumber)
   {
       DomainResult<PdfDocument> result = repo...;

       // result object might contain a BrokenRule containing a code/message
       // "Product couldn't be created because materialNumber wasn't found"

       return result;
   }
}
```

And then you can return a `404` in your Web API resource method depending on which rules have been broken during the domain transaction. Also, you should add these broken rule messages to the `ModelState` using `ModelState.AddModelError` within your API controller.

Comment: @Elisabeth BTW an HTTP response is impossible that couldn't return a status code :D

Comment: my service layer is http agnostic and should therefore not be coupled to http.

Comment: @Elisabeth How your service can be agnostic to HTTP if it's developed using ASP.NET Web API???????????

Comment: The service could be used in a NON-Http environment. With service I mean productService.cs not the abstract thing service for web service.

Comment: Ok so the Repository/Service/endpoint all share the DomainResult<T> correct?

Comment: When you have errors in the service class would you also add BrokenRules to the DomainResult?

Comment: @Elisabeth It'll depend on what you consider an error. If it's a possible exception, these won't be *broken rules*, but if some object isn't the right state to be processed or a data is missing, who knows, then yes, it's a broken rule. And yes, each layer should be adding broken rules to the domain result, also a service.

Comment: This DomainResult with BrokenRules collection seems to make most sense in a strong domain driven/much product business logic application. Maybe a rule can be seen more generalized like ErrorState or ValidationState just like the asp.net ModelStateDictionary ;-) For example when a duplicate key exception occurs.

Comment: @Elisabeth Well, at the end of the day this is another story/discussion ;P We can end up with a year conversation about the topic haha

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DomainResult](https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult) that comes with 2 tiny NuGet packages that provide a solution for separating the *Domain Layer* (aka *Business Layer*) from the *Application Layer*.

At its core, it has `IDomainResult` with properties:

```cs
IReadOnlyCollection<string> Errors { get; } // Collection of error messages if any
bool IsSuccess { get; }                     // Flag, whether the current status is successful or not
DomainOperationStatus Status { get; }       // Current status of the domain operation: Success, Failed, NotFound, etc.
```

And from here, you've got 2 options for the returned object in your method:

1. A generic `IDomainResult<T>` that extends the one above by adding `T Value { get; }` property.
2. Return [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) from methods, like `(T, IDomainResult)`.

It all is spiced up with 50+ extension methods, e.g.

```cs
// Successful result with an int
(value, state) = IDomainResult.Success(10);        // value = 10; state.Status is 'Success'
// The same but wrapped in a task
var res = IDomainResult.SuccessTask(10);           // res is Task<(int, IDomainResult)>

// Error message
IDomainResult = IDomainResult.Failed("Ahh!");       // res.Status is 'Failed' and res.Errors = new []{ "Ahh!" }
// Error when expected an int
(value, state) = IDomainResult.Failed<int>("Ahh!"); // value = 0, state.Status is 'Failed' and state.Errors = new []{ "Ahh!" }
```

Examples would be:

```cs
public async Task<(InvoiceResponseDto, IDomainResult)> GetInvoice(int invoiceId)
{
    if (invoiceId < 0)
        // Returns a validation error that later gets converted to HTTP code 400
        return IDomainResult.Failed<InvoiceResponseDto>("Try harder");

    var invoice = await DataContext.Invoices.FindAsync(invoiceId);
    
    if (invoice == null)
        // Returns a Not Found response that later gets converted to HTTP code 404
        return IDomainResult.NotFound<InvoiceResponseDto>();

    // Returns the invoice that later gets converted to HTTP code 200
    IDomainResult.Success(invoice);
}
```

or if you're against [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple), then a more traditional method signature:

```cs
public async Task<IDomainResult<InvoiceResponseDto>> GetInvoice(int invoiceId)
{
    if (invoiceId < 0)
        // Returns a validation error
        return DomainResult.Failed<InvoiceResponseDto>("Try harder");
    ...
}
```

It also has 40+ extensions to convert the `IDomainResult`-based types to corresponding `IActionResult` for returning from WebAPI controller methods and `IResult` for the modern [minimal API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis) (for .NET 6+). For example:

```cs
// Returns `IActionResult` with HTTP code `200 Ok` along with the value
IDomainResult<T>.ToActionResult();
(T, IDomainResult).ToActionResult();

// Returns `IResult` with HTTP code `200 Ok` along with the value
IDomainResult<T>.ToResult();
(T, IDomainResult).ToResult();
```

Check out the samples at https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult. It all yours.